# Create APK package from existing files

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux

I have a bunch of files in several directories and would like to create an APK package out of them and publish it in a private repository. For `dpkg-deb` + `apt-ftparchive` on Debian/Ubuntu or for `rpmbuild` + `createrepo` on RHEL/Fedora, such task is a piece of cake. But with `abuild`, I have no idea how to proceed.

Abuild seems to require that all sources are downloaded from upstream, built locally, packaged in a fakeroot including various binary stripping, path-based estimation of content for subpackaging and various other automagical tasks, which are definitely awesome, but completely unnecessary for my use case. Moreover abuild also seems to require that the APKBUILD files themselves are stored in a git repository.

I have read the articles on Alpine wiki rg. packaging and APKBUILD reference and I have also poked around in https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/abuild/tree/abuild.in, trying to figure out what exactly is going on when a package is built and I came up with the following steps:

```
# Create mock git repo to satisfy prepare_metafiles when it asks about commit hash
cd /my-build-root
git init   
git add APKBUILD 
git commit -m "mock repo"

# bindmount the directories into $pkgdir so it looks like they were built locally
mkdir /my-build-root/pkgname/pkg/pkgname
mount --bind /real-location-of-my-files /my-build-root/pkgname/pkg/pkgname

# Run the minimum needed abuild functions
abuild prepare_metafiles create_apks index
```

This produces more or less what I'm expecting, but the approach is wrong on so many levels that there has to be some better way.

How can I create an APK package from existing set of files without absolutely any changes (stripping, symlink fixing) done to the source files and preferably also without git?